# Samba Server Doesn't logging

Tags: centos, logging, samba, log-files

I'm trying to logging with Windows in a Samba Server, but it does not connect.
When I look in the logs it gives me the message

```
[2022/07/20 08:35:19.749737,  0] ../lib/param/loadparm.c:1844(lpcfg_do_service_parameter)
  Ignoring unknown parameter "plublic"
[2022/07/20 08:35:20.785155,  0] ../lib/param/loadparm.c:784(lpcfg_map_parameter)
  Unknown parameter encountered: "plublic"
[2022/07/20 08:35:20.785241,  0] ../lib/param/loadparm.c:1844(lpcfg_do_service_parameter)
  Ignoring unknown parameter "plublic"
[2022/07/20 08:35:34.675466,  0] ../lib/param/loadparm.c:784(lpcfg_map_parameter)
  Unknown parameter encountered: "plublic"
[2022/07/20 08:35:34.675534,  0] ../lib/param/loadparm.c:1844(lpcfg_do_service_parameter)
  Ignoring unknown parameter "plublic"
```

I didn't find anything about this error or what is this `lpcfg`.
The computer where I'm trying to log in says that I'm not allowed to login in the server.

Here are the configs from samba

```
[global]
        smb ports = 139
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        security = user
        dns proxy = No
        netbios name = MyServer
        server string = Compartilhamento
        name resolve order = lmhosts, host, wins, bcast
        wins support = yes
        cups options = raw
        load printers = yes
        workgroup = WORKGROUP
        os level = 100
        auto services = global
        interfaces = lo eth1 192.168.1.0/24
        hosts allow = 127. 192.168.1.
        passdb backend = tdbsam
        encrypt passwords = yes
        max log size = 250
        preferred master = Yes
        domain master = Yes
        domain logons = yes
        logon path = %Nprofiles%u
        syslog = 0
        invalid users = root
[MyServer]
        comment = Diretorio compartilhado
        path = /home/share
        public = yes
        writable = yes
        browseable = yes
        printable = no
        write list = +staff
        create mode = 0775
        directory mode = 0775
[printers]
        comment = All Printers
        path = /var/spool/samba
        browseable = yes
        guest ok = yes
        plublic = yes
        writable = no
        printable = yes
        use client driver = yes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there is an error in your `[printers]` section where `public` is misspelled as `plublic` which is most likely the source of your log messages.

Try fixing that and login again after restarting the samba service

Comment: Hi, thank you. I really didn't see that. But I still can not login, but now it doesn't give me any error in the logs. Do you know what it can be?